# Node-RED: JS 'TypeError' but code is working as expected

Tags: node-red

I am currently taking my first steps with Node-RED. I created a flow which stores data into a .json file as soon as any of the MQTT - clients sends data.
So far everything is working as expected but i still get

> function : (error)
> "TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')"

In my node-red debugging console. When the line is commented out, it doesnt work anymore.
Anyone knows whether this is a node-red issue or do i need to update/include something?
Is there a way for further debugging?

Any help is appreciated.

My flow:

[image]

Error message:

[image]

This is my function node code:

```
context.mqtt = context.mqtt || {};
context.filedata = context.filedata || {};

if (msg.topic === "mqtt_data_available"){
    context.mqtt = msg.payload;
} else if (msg.topic === "filedata"){
    context.filedata = msg.payload;
}

if(context.mqtt && context.filedata){
    msg.payload.devicedata[context.filedata.devicedata.length] = context.mqtt;
    return msg;
} else {
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `if` only tests if `context.filedata` exists not if `context.filedata.devicedata` exists.

So if `devicedata` doesn't exist then there will be no `devicedata.length`

Also since you are using `context.mqtt = context.mqtt || {}` and `context.filedata = context.filedata || {}` they will always evaluate to `true` (unless `msg.payload` is `undefined`) so the that if will always evaluate to true.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Now i understand what is happening. I will use a catch-node for that error, since my implementation needs that first execution to throw it.